# External hard drive not visible

Tags: usb-drive, external-hdd, data-loss

I'm using **Ubuntu 16.10**. Right after login and while starting up I made the mistake to **plug in my external hard drive** (500GB). The computer got stuck, so I had to turn it off pressing the "off" button.

Now I turned it back on **I cannot see my external hard drive** (that was working until yesterday). I (finally) wait for the whole startup to finish, I plug it in, hear some mechanical movement inside the hdd for a couple of seconds and then it stops.

I tried with `lusb` and here's what I get:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 064e:9700 Suyin Corp. Asus Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

How to understand if my laptop sees the hdd? How to figure out if I lost my data?

Note: I tried with **GParted** but it doesn't see it. I also just tried to see it using Ubuntu 16.04 on the same laptop and it has the same problem.

Here's the output I get from `lsblk`.

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 232,9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0 132,3G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0  92,7G  0 part /
└─sda5   8:5    0   7,5G  0 part [SWAP]
```

And here's part (without all `/dev/ram*` entries) of the output I get running `sudo fdisk -l`.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 232,9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6B31D035-7AE6-4BD3-8CEA-C4A78DC331D7

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1050624 278394373 277343750 132,3G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  278394880 472769879 194375000  92,7G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda5  472770560 488396799  15626240   7,5G Linux swap
```

Apparently it keeps ignoring the existence of the external hdd.

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**
I just tried the hdd on a **different computer** (with ubuntu 16.04) and **it works**!
On the other hand, going back to the laptop it keeps not working. What can it  be the problem?

Comment: Additionally could you please provide the output of `lsblk` and `fdisk -l`.

Comment: @Hölderlin thanks for the suggestion. I updated the post as requested.

Comment: Was your external hard drive connected when you did run the commands?

Comment: @Hölderlin of course

Comment: Try to boot ubuntu or a similar distribution from live dvd and check if you can access your external hard drive, if not show the output from `lsblk` if the output is different with respect to the  partition of your external hard drive.

Comment: Does it appears in Disk ?

Comment: Start your laptop and in terminal issue `dmesg -w`, then plug in your disk and look what messages appear. Post them to your question. If nothing happens, try another USB port.